# I can't select winform app from taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to create a winform. I can build and run the form. However, occasionally, while the form is performing a task, I can no longer see it. That is, I see it in the taskbar, and I can preview it if I hover over its icon, but clicking on the icon doesn't bring up the form. I also can't access it through alt-tab. When the form has finished doing its task, it pops back up.

I'm not sure if this is related, but the same behavior happens when I try to debug the form. I can run and attach it, but when I click on a button on the form, the entire form disappears. Once the debugging session is completed, it comes back.

Comment: *"while the form is performing a task"* You are probably running long calculations on the UI thread, which is preventing your application from focusing and redrawing. Move the "task" off to a `Task` or background thread of some sort. Its difficult to tell you what to do without seeing the "task" that you are performing.

Comment: You're right, I was running long calculations, including querying outside servers. I followed sparta93's advice, and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your task is inside a method, call it like this below and it will not freeze the UI. To Run your task, simply call `BeginProcessingAsync(d);`.

```
private async void BeginProcessingAsync(Data d)
{
    //Execute the long running task asynchronously
    await Task.Run(() =>  yourMethod(d));

    //Anything after the await line will be executed only after the task is finished.
    DoSomethingWithFinishedData(d);
}
```

Also, please note: If you're using newer versions of .NET, you might have to use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => yourMethod(d));` instead of the above.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the same behavior is supposed to happen when debugging the form?

Comment: @user218750 I'm not entirely sure but probably not... you should give it a try and tell me

Comment: I meant that when I debug the form, it disappears until after I stepped through all of the steps.